# Find usages of async where await is not used in Visual Studio or Unit Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await

I'm currently working on a large application that makes extensive use of the async and await keywords in C#.  Our IO calls are asynchronous pretty much throughout.

When using an async call that does not await (unintentionally, because a developer forgot to use it), it's possible to encounter task cancellations and other undesired behavior as a consequence of not awaiting the result.

E.g. `doSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)` vs

```
 await doSomethingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)
```

Is there any way I can succinctly identify usages of async methods that are not awaiting properly?

Ideally it's something we could unit test (we use DI throughout as well).  Simple method tests are unreliable because the task completing essentially becomes a race condition, where it will succeed often, and fail occasionally.

If unit testing for this is not possible, is there a way to search for and isolate these instances in-mass?

Comment: It shouldn't be very hard to make a diagnostic in Roslyn, if you have access to that toolset.

Comment: In an `async` method unawaited tasks show up as warnings.

Comment: Just wondering if resharper can do it?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, we're using VS2013 at the moment which sounds like is not the ideal version to work with Roslyn.  We'll adopt "14" as soon as it's officially released, so that may be a great option when we get there,

Comment: @I3arnon, Oh cool, you're right. So, I just took a look at that, and it turns out Resharper can help.  I can tell it to identify any instances of that warning in the solution, and it looks like it does the trick! I clicked on the Resharper light-bulb next to one instance and it's in the options of that context menu.

Comment: If not Roslyn, what about just compiling the module and looking for the compiler warning in the compiler output?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I just looked at that as well.  Seems that warning is slightly different.  You get the compiler warning if the method is marked as async and NO calls are awaited.  We have instances where multiple calls are made in the same method, so if even one instance uses it, the warning is cleared.

Comment: Yes, it's true, you get a different warning for an `async` method without any `await`, versus a call returning an awaitable without an `await` (or rather, not using the `Task` at all, either with `await` or putting it in a variable, etc.). The latter does generate a warning though. Still, if a tool like Resharper does the trick, that seems more convenient.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, good to know.  I must not be capturing that warning for some reason, perhaps it's not enabled, i'll look at that as well.

Comment: See `CS4014`. I.e. "warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."

Comment: The easiest way is probably to just turn on "treat all warnings as errors". That will force your team to clean up their code. :)

Comment: The problem here is it's possible to make a CS4014 'go away' by assigning it to a Task. eg. `Task t = DelayAndThrow();` If I never await this the end result is identical to if I'd just had `DelayAndThrow()` by itself. Problem is how do I find these? I'm pretty sure I have some, but if I used `var t = DelayAndThrow` I'm stuck!

Answer (score 3):

There is a VS extension called AsyncFixer which tries to make recommendations.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SemihOkur.AsyncFixer#qna

It may help, but unfortunately can't locate this pattern:

`Task t = DelayAndThrowAsync();`   // Never awaited!

You can explicitly do this to make the task 'go away', and it was an acceptable stop gap before my whole codebase was async - but now it pretty much is I need to find the offending unawaited tasks.

The problem is that `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` doesn't actually tell me where the offending task was :-/

Comment: This extension ended up giving me false corrections so I had to uninstall it. I forget exactly what it did but the code was legitimate and it said it wasn’t.